# create-react-native-app failed to build javascript bundle when running using Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I installed create-react-native-app on my machine to start working with React Native and was stopped by this error on the npm start step itself.

Current Environment:

node - 6.14.0
npm - 3.10.10
Expo - 2.3.0.1012011

On my terminal I am getting - "Failed building JavaScript bundle" at 96 percent.

On my phone when I click "Show Details" I am getting - "Error Code: CLIENT_LOADING_ERROR Status Code: 500"

```
/<location to folder>/FirstApp/node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Entypo.ttf: Cannot find module '/<location to folder>/FirstApp/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles'

ABI24_0_0RCTFBQuickPerformanceLoggerConfigureHooks
ABI25_0_0RCTFBQuickPerformanceLoggerConfigureHooks
<redacted>
<redacted>
<redacted>
<redacted>
<redacted>
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
UIApplicationMain
Exponent
<redacted>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "node_module" directory  using $sudo rm -r node_module 
then run the $npm install command to reinstall node_modules if asked use "sudo"

Comment: I tried that. I also tried using yarn instead of npm but I keep ending up on this screen. I don't know what I am missing here.